# Note taking software with link to PDFs

Tags: note-taking, macos

I need a non-linear note taking, I tried personal wiki, but they seem to be too difficult for me without any basic programming knowledge and issues.

I need a basic, macOS, personal wiki-based software with link to PDFs. Main aim is to make a collection to text with link to my PDFs that are stored locally.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/), which is free for personal use.

Obsidian allows you to write notes using Markdown format and allows you to link to other notes, making it work like a personal wiki.

You can also link to files in the "attachments" folder. When doing this with a PDF, clicking the link opens the PDF in the app.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried. But, two issues: a) the PDF must be always kept in the working folder and b) the PDF opens in the same window or say in the app, I want to make the highlight if needed, and typically want to open PDF in my default app, Skim. I guess these belong to some features request section of the app.